# Problem 9.12 of Rotman's Homological Algebra, Assumption not Needed?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

[image]

Hello all, I'm attempting the second part of ex 9.12 above and it seems like I don't need to use the assumption that "this sequence is not split" to show the result so I'm not sure if I did something wrong or not.  My attempt is below:

[image]

I know if the sequence splits then $A = A' \oplus A''$ which would implies $pd(A) = \max\{pd(A'),pd(A'')\}$ so we really don't need to prove anything but I don't know why we need to include that in the assumption.  Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.

The situation is more interesting when $\operatorname{pd}(A'')=\operatorname{pd}(A')+1$ (i.e., swapping the roles of $A'$ and $A''$), and I think that the exercise that Rotman meant to set was probably something like:

"Moreover, unless this sequence is not split and $\operatorname{pd}(A'')=\operatorname{pd}(A')+1$, then the inequality is equality."

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation.  With the modification, assume $pd(A') = n$ so $pd(A'')=n+1$.  From the LES, I can show that $\text{Ext}^{n+2}(A,B) = 0$ for all $B$ and as before, to show that $pd(A) = n+1 = \max\{pd(A'),pd(A'')\}$, I need to show that $\text{Ext}^{n+1}(A,B) \neq 0$ for some $B$.  If $\text{Ext}^{n+1}(A,B) = 0$ for all $B$, then we have that the map $\text{Ext}^{n}(A',B) \to \text{Ext}^{n+1}(A'',B) $ is onto.  To get a contradiction, I think we want to somehow show that $ \text{Ext}^{n+1}(A'',C) \neq 0$ but $ \text{Ext}^{n}(A'',C) = 0 $ for some $C$.

Comment: But I'm not sure how to do this, I know we have $ \text{Ext}^{n+1}(A'',B)  \neq 0$ for some $B$ since $pd(A'') = n+1$ but $ \text{Ext}^{n}(A',B) $ might be nonzero as well.   Or I can show that the map is onto implies that the sequence splits but I'm not sure how to do that.  Can you give me some hint?  Thank you so much.

Comment: @Khoata Note that as well as swapping $A’$ and $A’’$, I also changed “if” to “unless”. So the modified exercise is asking you to show that the situation you are considering is the only case when equality might *not* hold.

Comment: Sorry, English is not my native language and I'm kinda confused about the wording, so the equivalent way of saying the modified problem is  "the inequality is equality if and only if this sequence splits or $pd(A'') \neq pd(A')+1$ ", is this what you meant? Thank you

Comment: @Khoata The inequality is equality if the sequence splits or $\operatorname{pd}(A’’)\neq\operatorname{pd}(A’)+1$. But not if and only if.